# Generic class with generic delegate. How can I distinguish which object's delegate is executing the callback?

Tags: swift, generics

MyClass is a generic class which has a generic delegate.
AClass contains two iVar instances of MyClass and also implements MyClassDelegate.

Where AClass implements MyClassDelegate, how can I distinguish which object is calling into the interface? With non-generic classes, == is acceptable.

Please see the comments and error messages at the bottom of this code snippet.

```
protocol MyClassDelegate: class {
   func myClass<T>(_ myClass: MyClass<T>, valueDidChange value: T)
}

class MyClass<T: Comparable> {
    private var _value: T
    var value: T {
        set {
            delegate?.myClass(self, valueDidChange: newValue)
        }
        get {
            return _value
        }
    }
    var delegate: MyClassDelegate?
    init(value: T) {
        _value = value
    }
}

class AClass {
    private var thing1 = MyClass(value: Int(10))
    private var thing2 = MyClass(value: Int(100))
    private var thing3 = MyClass(value: TimeInterval(10))
    private var thing4 = MyClass(value: TimeInterval(100))

    init() {
        thing1.delegate = self
        thing2.delegate = self
        thing3.delegate = self
        thing4.delegate = self
    }
}

extension AClass: MyClassDelegate {
    func myClass<T>(_ myClass: MyClass<T>, valueDidChange value: T) {
        // This fails to complile
        // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyClass<T>' and 'MyClass<Int>'
        if myClass == thing1 {

        }
        // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyClass<T>' and 'MyClass<TimeInterval>' (aka 'MyClass<Double>')
        else if myClass == thing3 {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the `T` type in your *protocol* method signature `func myClass<T>(...)` to be `Comparable`. Since you restricted it only in one particular extension of that protocol, the method in `AClass` can take *any* kind of `T`, not just `Comparable` ones.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tried but couldn't configure the generic delegate in a manner where I could compare callers.

I read the answer from NRitH, but couldn't get the compiler to accept the syntax. Perhaps there is a way to do this, but I went a different route with success.

I gave up on the protocol/delegate technique and ended up using a callback closure. Instead of defining a delegate in MyClass and implementing that delegate in AClass, I defined a callback closure in MyClass in implemented that in AClass like so:

```
class MyClass<T: Comparable>: Equatable {

    var valueChanged: ((_ clazz: MyClass) -> Void)?

    private var _value: T
    var value: T {
        set {
            _value = newValue
            valueChanged?(self)
        }
        get {
            return _value
        }
    }
    init(value: T) {
        _value = value
    }
    static public func ==(lhs: MyClass<T>, rhs: MyClass<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }

}

class AClass {
    fileprivate var thing1: MyClass<Int> = MyClass(value: 10)
    fileprivate var thing2: MyClass<Int> = MyClass(value: 100)
    fileprivate var thing3: MyClass<TimeInterval> = MyClass(value: 10)
    fileprivate var thing4: MyClass<TimeInterval> = MyClass(value: 100)


    init() {
        thing1.valueChanged = { (thing) in
            // You can compare here, but you already know which object is callling back
            if thing == self.thing1 {

            }
        }

        thing2.valueChanged = { (thing) in
            print("Thing2 changed: \(thing.value)")
        }

    }
}
```